# ionic not showing "Done" label for dropdown HTML select tag

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am building hybrid app using ionic. I am using some forms fields on the app. Those fields includes some HTML select tags. It is working perfectly on android but when I test it on iPhone, it does not allow me to leave the HTML select options as it does not display "Done" label. [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5iNYhRnlfTUbnJIUzhJdGxKU0U) is the link of the screenshot.

I have commented these lines but no change is reflected when I test it on iPhone:

```
   if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  //cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
}
```

I have also tried this: `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);`
Again "Done" label is not showing on iPhone.

Any solutions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of what keyboard plugin are you using? Can you run `cordova plugins` and share the name of the plugin and the version?

Comment: Dexter I ran 'cordova plugins' and here is the list of plugins of the project
<br />
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"


cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"

cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.1 "Splashscreen"

cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.1 "StatusBar"

cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"

ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"

Comment: This is supposed to work, do you see any errors in the console when you have `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);` in your code?

Comment: @Dexter I don't have any errors in the console. I tried as 'cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);' didn't work (no change).

Comment: I have also put HTML5 select tag but still the problem persists. The options are displaying fine but there is no way to select or cancel or leave that option control.